# What formula do I need to use to update an inventory using an updated spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Here's my question, I'll try to be as clear as I can.  I am in charge of keeping our inventory up to date, (our company sells products to customers using several different online stores).  I have two inventory spreadsheets - one for the online store I need to update, and one for our current inventory.  Is there a formula that I can use on the online store spreadsheet so that it reflects the correct inventory numbers from our current inventory spreadsheet?

I've read several places that a VLOOKUP function would be the best, but my biggest problem is that the quantities listed on the online store spreadsheet are all formatted as text instead of numbers, and it's giving me an error every time I try to use the formula.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use one spreadsheet for onilne and non-online and avoid updating all together?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your online store entries with `=value()` in your formula.  This will force Excel to treat them as numbers.

Example: `=vlookup(value(a1),$B:$D,2,false)`